# Problems with uniform_int_distribution

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I have a pretty basic question which after looking around across the internet, I thought I was doing it correct. I want to generate a random distribution using `uniform_int_distribution`.

I have this code in my project, compiled with *C++11* standards

```
uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0,5);
```

I get the error:

```
uniform_int_distribution was not declared in this scope.
```

I thought I was initializing it with the previous statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is consistent with you leaving off `std::`, so you should use it like follows:

```
 std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0,5);
```

See it working [live](http://rextester.com/NLXO32705).

Note as WhozCraig mentioned you also need to include the [random](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) header:

```
#include <random>
```

Comment: +1 And, of course, `#include <random>` (but I hope the OP at least got that right).

Comment: i have include random, when i change it to that i get‘uniform_int_distribution’ is not a member of ‘std’

Comment: as well as expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
,error: ‘dis’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: @JoshHamet That sounds like you do not have *C++11* turned on, what compiler are you using? In `gcc` and `clang` either using `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x`would turn on *C++11*.